# Sending GPS & Google Maps link through SMS

Tags: android, gps, sms

Hi I have all permissions done and my SMS message is working fine and sending a text off the emulator. However, I am trying to send a link with the specific coordinates (long, lat) that send the users coordinates in a link to Google maps. I'm struggling to pass the google maps link and coordinates into one string. Any help would be great, here is what I have:

```
 btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GPSTracker gpsT = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
                Location l = gpsT.getLocation();
                if (l != null) {
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lon = l.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + lat + "\n Long: " + lon,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(myCarerDB.getCarerNumber(), null,
                            "Hi I am here.. http://www.google.com/maps/place/lat,lon ", null, null);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the link by appending lat long to end of the string.
This can be done like

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(myCarerDB.getCarerNumber(), null, 
"Hi I am here.. http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+lat+","+long, null, null);
```